# Netsuite make saved search populate value in custom field

Tags: scheduled-tasks, netsuite

In our Netsuite under Transactions. -> Order management - > Commit Orders -> Schedule
we have a scheduled commitment task that runs a saved search to get all open orders that need to have stock committed to the order.

However if/once an order gets stock committed to it I need a custom field labeled released by cs and released to the warehouse populated with a 'Yes' value. My thought was that I could maybe alter the saved search used to populate these fields when the line items get committed. but I am looking for a tutorial or documentation that may help me and hoping the community might have some suggestions on where I could go to learn how best to set this up?